# Why does my same CD player show up multiple times in Nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, cd-drive

Every time I unplug and replug my CD player into the USB port, another clone of the CD shows up in Nautilus/the unity sidebar. See example screenshot. Whenever I click on one of the CD’s, all three “light up” in the unity sidebar.

Why is this happening? This isn’t really impeding anything I do unless I reload the CD player a lot of times but I’m still curious as to why this occurs.

[image]